# Where did my $500,000 car go in GTA 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So no I didn't leave it lying around I put it back in one of my personal garages. I went to go and retrieve it but no cars showed up in the garage. I have gone to impound and it's not there. This is single player (hate multiplayer) is it gone forever or is it a known glitch? If so, is it worth buying cars if they're just gonna up and leave?

I've already seen the other question and no it doesn't answer it because I didn't leave it lying around, I put it back in my personal garage (not house)

Comment: By "single player", do you mean the story mode or the GTA Online mode but solo?

Comment: Story Mode thx for replying